# Handle iglob error when path to search doesn't exist

Tags: python

I'm trying to use iglob instead of glob to get a list of say .txt files. If no .txt files exist, glob doesn't return any errors, but iglob does.

Code:

```
def iGlobLatest():
    dir_list = glob.iglob('*.txt')
    print dir_list.next()
```

if no .txt files exist, I get this:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "T:\prod\offlineValidation\scripts\goofin.py", line 98, in  iGlobLatest()

File "T:\prod\offlineValidation\scripts\goofin.py", line 88, in iGlobLatest print dir_list.next()

StopIteration

If I use try/except, I can avoid the error, but is that the only way? Other suggestions for checking the existence of .txt files involve using glob, but since I'm trying to use iglob instead of glob....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `iglob()` is a generator, it raises `StopIteration` once all matching files are exhausted.  If there is no file at all, it will raise `StopIteration` upon the first call of `next()`.

Generators are meant to iterate over:

```
for file in glob.iglob('*.txt'):
    # whatever
```

This way, the `StopIteration` exception will be implicitly caught for you.  I don't know what you are actually trying to do, but maybe this is what you want:

```
return next(dir_list, None)   # return first item of dir_list,
                              # or None if no files match
```

(Python 2.6 or above.)

Comment: I think its also good to specifically note that iglob is not the call raising the exception, as stated by the op. It doesn't respond any differently than the glob call beside the return type. Its the call to the return type (the generator) that raises the exception, the same as if you had tried to say `l = glob('foo'); l[0]`, if glob didn't return any results.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know you could also go through an iterator with next(iterator). And this also explains why I saw the exception when I used iglob() the way I did versus glob().

Comment: @itchmyback: `next(iterator)` does the same as `iterator.next()`.  The latter form does not allow to provide a default value in case the iterator is exhausted, though.